# Generated asynchronous method calls in C# - AOP?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, aop, business-logic

I am working on an WPF application that uses a BusinessLogic layer (currently a single dll) in which I created my BL methods that will be called directly from the UI. Each BL manager is resolved with Unity (thinking on switching to MEF though...). BL classes implements a specific interface that have of course apropriate methods.

Now, what I want is to create (or rather to GENERATE) a new asynchronous-aspect-like assembly (or more...) that should have similar methods/operations defined as in my original assembly (the same parameters...) and also a callback delegate as a parameter. 
So basically I want async methods to be generated with some framework out there...

Besides the usual call to:
User userBO = Resolve().Login("name", "pass");
I'd like to use something similar with:
Resolve().Login("name", "pass", delegate(object, SomeArgs e) { User userBO = e.Args....};

Now, I want this assembly to be generated instead of writing new eventArgs and delegates for each method.
I am aware that PostSharp could help in AOP task, but I coulnd't find anything regarding this code generation mechanism in a new dll for asynchronous methods.

Is there a way to achieve this using a third party tool or do I have to rewrite the whole async thing manually?

Any ideas are welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: You could always write your own tool to create BeginXXX EndXXX method pairs and place them into a partial class - similar to how the web service references code gen works.  The plumbing of the code is largely the same, so is a perfect candidate for automating.  I don't know of a third party tool off the top of my head for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a tool that will do this for you, but there's an easy way to wrap them in `Task` objects. This is easier at least than manually defining `Async` methods and `event` callbacks.

The general concept is to run the method as a `Task` and then schedule a task continuation to the UI thread.

First, define a scheduler (you don't need to do this every time; it could be a global var or a window-level var):

```
TaskScheduler ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

then when you want to call a method and handle its return value:

```
var bll = Resolve();
Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => bll.Login("name", "pass"))
  .ContinueWith(task =>
  {
    // Note: accessing Result will raise any exceptions thrown by Login
    User userBO = task.Result;
    ...
  }, ui);
```

It's not quite as pretty as your suggested syntax, but it's usable. The task continuation passed to `ContinueWith` will run on the UI thread, so it is safe to update the UI or any databound objects.

`Task` objects also fully support other common asynchronous scenarios, in particular cancellation and progress reporting.

Since this approach doesn't actually add events to the class, it should be possible to write a `T4` template to generate extension methods for you (e.g., `LoginTask(string username, string password, Action<Task<User>> continuation)`).

Comment: Looks interesting - how does this behave when the task is blocking?  Does the UI block?

Comment: Thanks guys for the info, I'll need to digg into T4 templates. So far, I only used them in EF. I was thinking on asynchronous interfaces because of the synthactical sugar it provides:
IUser blUser = Resolve().Login(...) and then IUserAsynchronous = Resolve().LoginAsync(...., callback)...

Comment: I believe I'm going to write this tool myself..It would be nice if this tool would create async methods whenever I create a new BL method for example and build the project. just thoughts...So that the output async dll would contain the appropriate async method as well....

Comment: Personally, I prefer task continuations. But if you like the `IAsyncInvoke` style, note that the `Task` class does in fact implement `IAsyncInvoke`. So you can return it from your `BeginLogin` method and pull the result out in your `EndLogin` method.